# How to automate database backup of windows machines

Tags: windows, filesystems, cloud-storage, backup

I have a network containing 10 Windows workstations and 1  Windows 7 machine which acts as a server. I am planning to take a monthly backup of a folder called "MYFILES" which will be on all of the machines. Each folder size will not be greater than 300MB.

I am thinking of buying a external hard drive and manually copy the folders from all machines. Is it a good idea to buy a new hard drive or should I automate the backup process so that manual task will not be involved?

How do I automate so that all 10 machines folders will be backed up in the cloud as well?

Can we write a script in server so that it will take backup of all machines and stores it? Can it put those files in amazon s3 or whatever?

Comment: Asking something like "what's a free service for this?" isn't allowed. We don't do shopping questions. The rest of your question is OK, so I'll just edit out the shopping bits, so that it doesn't get closed.

Comment: And I'm confused about what, if anything, this has to do with a database... while we're on the topic of things that don't belong in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The standard approach is *not* to back up every machine in your organization. This isn't scalable.

What you need to do it get a file server, redirect everyone's My Documents to it (or just map a network drive and tell them to use that instead of My Documents). This way, all business-critical files  are in a central location.

Now that everything is centralized, you can use any backup software that you like and you only need to back up the server. If a workstation dies, just replace it and reconfigure the folder redirection or drive mapping and the user will have immediate access to all of the data that they had before without having to do a restore.